# pandoc does not recognize Chinese characters

Tags: xetex, cjk, pandoc, bash

I want to compile, with `pandoc`, a Markdown document containing CJK elements (Chinese, actually). 
It was stated [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18178084/pandoc-and-foreign-characters) that `--latex-engine=xelatex` option allows `pandoc` to compile Unicode characters.

However, I tried
cjk.md:

```
Hello
你好
```

compiled with (in bash)

```
pandoc -s -o cjk.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex cjk.md
```

But the resulting `.pdf` has `Hello` shown only, while `你好` is not shown. 
Have I missed something?

(Yesterday I asked this in Stack overflow, but no one paid attention to me.... and people there are scary to me ><" )

background: I plan to ask quite many question in Math SE, and want to minimize the trouble converting them to another file convenient to compile on local. 
Mandarin is my native, I sometimes desire to add comments in Chinese (for my own reference only). 
If I cannot find a easy way to compile, on local, markdown documents embedded with LaTeX and strewn with few Chinese words, my motivation to do all these would be discouraged.

Comment: See the [Pandoc FAQ, question "I get a blank document when I try to convert a markdown document in Chinese to pdf…"](http://pandoc.org/faqs.html#i-get-a-blank-document-when-i-try-to-convert-a-markdown-document-in-chinese-to-pdf-using-pandoc--o-test.pdf-test.markdown.) Its answer follows: By default, pandoc uses pdflatex to generate the PDF, and pdflatex doesn’t handle Chinese characters. But you can change the default to use xelatex instead. You should also make sure you’re using a font with Chinese glyphs. For example: `pandoc -o c.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex -V mainfont='Adobe Ming Std'`

Comment: The Pandoc FAQ doesn't mention this, but note that you probably need a font (probably a Unicode font in Opentype format) that contains glyphs for _both_ Chinese and English characters (if your documents contain both scripts).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion to PDF uses LaTex as the backend. You will need to specify a suitable mainfont with chinese glyphs.
You can do this by putting the following section at the top of your .md document, e.g.

```
---
mainfont: Noto Sans Mono CJK TC
---
```

Then compile with the --latex-engine=xelatex switch and you should have your desired output. Note: run fc-list from a terminal to see which CJK fonts are installed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no real need for modifying the Pandoc LaTeX template if you just need to render Chinese characters in your document. The following compiles fine:

```
---
CJKmainfont: Noto Sans CJK SC Regular
CJKoptions: AutoFakeBold
---

Hello
你好

**你好**
```

I used the following command to compile the above,

```
pandoc -t latex -o cjk.pdf --latex-engine=xelatex cjk.md
```

I've highlighted the required part of the intermediate `LaTeX` file generated as follows:

```
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[AutoFakeBold]{Noto Sans CJK SC Regular}
\fi
```

If you really intend to edit the Pandoc template, then it's better to make it flexible for future use. Instead of hard-coding your options, introduce variables instead. Thus,

```
$if(CJKmainfont)$
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[$for(CJKoptions)$$CJKoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmainfont$}
    $if(CJKsansfont)$
      \setCJKsansfont[$for(CJKsansoptions)$$CJKsansoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKsansfont$}
    $endif$
    $if(CJKmonofont)$
      \setCJKmonofont[$for(CJKmonooptions)$$CJKmonooptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmonofont$}
    $endif$
$endif$
```

We can then use the following source as input through the template,

```
---
CJKmainfont: STSong
CJKoptions: BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti

CJKsansfont: STXihei
CJKsansoptions: BoldFont=STHeiti

CJKmonofont: STFangsong
---

Hello
你好

**你好**
```

which would give us the intermediate LaTeX file as follows (I've just highlighted the important part):

```
\else % if luatex or xelatex
  \ifxetex
    \usepackage{mathspec}
  \else
    \usepackage{fontspec}
  \fi
  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=MatchLowercase}
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
          \setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=STHeiti]{STXihei}
              \setCJKmonofont[]{STFangsong}
    \fi
```

This way, your template is more flexible as these options can be changed directly from the Markdown files.

Comment: You are right.... why does it take me so long to know all I had to do is alter `CJKmainfont`? @blue_tiger300 is wrong. If I specify a CJK font to be a `mainfont`, `pandoc` does not recognize either. Also, since I copied pandoc-provided template elsewhere and did not overwrite original one, I think it is okay to hard-code it at my will.

Comment: If you use the same fonts and options all the time for CJK, then hard coding is not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I typed that in Stack Overflow, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892725/pandoc-does-not-recognize-chinese-characters/). But SE dislikes me just post a link (and no more), so I now copy it here.

---

Tl;dr: it's not enough to set compiler to be `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`; one has to include package `xeCJK` as well, but for where it should be, see below.

---

In my case, `pandoc` reads a `.md`, converts it to be a `.tex`, and call compiler to compile that to be a `.pdf`. 
Thus, in theory, what I can do normally with a tex-like compiler, can be done with `pandoc` as well --- it is only that I have to specify required template.

The `pandoc` calls its own latex template, which we can `cat` in the terminal by a prewritten command:

```
pandoc -D latex > default.latex
```

This essentially copies a new file `default.latex` to `.` (current directory). 
It is this I now modify. 
Append this option to `pandoc` when compiling:

```
--template=my-directory/my-template.latex
```

In the past I type Chinese characters (or more generally, CJK), I use a template beginning with

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xeCJK}% use Latin font whenever possible
\usepackage{fontspec}% set Chinese fonts, as follows
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
\setCJKsansfont[BoldFont=STHeiti]{STXihei}
\setCJKmonofont{STFangsong}
% .... whatever xeCJK commands you use
```

The fonts should be those your system permits; these shown above are shipped with mac.

But when I simply pasted this into the pandoc-provied template, there were many cryptic error messages

```
option clash for package XXXX....
```

This was because the pandoc-proviede template already defined `xeCJK`. Indeed, search these lines:

```
$if(CJKmainfont)$
    \usepackage{xeCJK}
    \setCJKmainfont[$for(CJKoptions)$$CJKoptions$$sep$,$endfor$]{$CJKmainfont$}
$endif$
```

These lines (quoted part) should be replaced by

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKmainfont[BoldFont=STHeiti,ItalicFont=STKaiti]{STSong}
% .... and so on, whatever you call from xeCJK
```

i.e., delete `if`, so that `xeCJK` is always executed; otherwise, `xeCJK` line will not be copied to the intermediate `.tex` file.
And also delete `\usepackage{fontspec}`, because it is called by `pandoc` by default, otherwise error message occurs for packages are called twice in the intermediate `.tex` file.

---

acknowledgement: [[1]](http://www.cnblogs.com/liuyangnuts/archive/2013/04/23/3038354.html) [[2]](http://jiangfeng.org/notes/2013/04/19/markdown-with-pdf.html) [[3]](https://afoo.me/posts/2013-07-10-how-to-transform-chinese-pdf-with-pandoc.html)

Sorry I didn't keep track of every websites from which I referenced, but none gets it all right anyway, or are outdated. 
Of most help is [mb21](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214446/mb21), who suggested in the comment that I output `.tex` *to debug*, after which I found `xeCJK` was not included.

I have spent some 10+ hrs on this issue, but from now on I can happily type Chinese in a markdown file. 
I have wrote this down for poor posterity's sake.