# Pandoc CJK & Greek MWE's Greek alphabet spacing too wide

Tags: luatex, miktex, greek, pandoc, cjk

## Background

I'm preparing a series of [simple document templates](https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/page/simple-document-templates/) on my personal site.  To allow readers who have never used [image: pandoc logo][pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) to see the visual output, I added some [image: HTML5 logo] `<object class="responsive-embed">` to allow visual output display of the [image: PDF logo] PDF, [image: Word logo] DOCX and [image: HTML5 logo] HTML from [image: VS code logo] [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) plugin [vscode-pandoc](https://github.com/dfinke/vscode-pandoc).

[image: screenshot of my page]

## Problem

Thanks to [pandoc does not recognize Chinese characters](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341809/126386), I know that setting `CJKmainfont` allows [image: pandoc logo][pandoc](/questions/tagged/pandoc) to render CJK characters.  However, it breaks the existing greek alphabets in the [image: PDF logo] [output PDF](https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/page/simple-document-templates/cjk-article.pdf).

[image: screenshot of my page's PDF embed]
Click the above screenshot to view [image: HTML5 logo] [my page](https://vincenttam.gitlab.io/page/simple-document-templates/#i-classfa-solid-fa-language-fa-lgi-i-classfa-solid-fa-scroll-fa-lgi-cjk-articles).

## Method

The above sample documents are produced on another device.  To let you see the undesirable visual output, I've prepared two MWEs.

| group | target | control |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Markdown source file name | `cjk_article.md` | `article.md` |
| Greek alphabets in file content | ✓ | ✓ |
| CJK characters in file content | ✓ | ✗ |
| `mainfont` | `Times New Roman` | `Times New Roman` |
| `CJKmainfont` | `Noto Sans CJK SC` | absent |
| CJK characters rendered | ✓ | ✗ |
| Greek alphabet spacing | ✗ | ✓ |

I've chosen `standalone` instead of `article` for `documentclass` in order to produce PDF files that will be converted to PNG with `pdftoppm`, so that the steps and output are reproducible.

```
$ diff -u {,cjk_}article.md
--- article.md  2023-04-08 12:59:46.415084100 +0200
+++ cjk_article.md      2023-04-08 13:02:34.029625600 +0200
@@ -1,6 +1,7 @@
 ---
 documentclass: standalone
 mainfont: Times New Roman
+CJKmainfont: Noto Sans CJK SC
 ---

-Section Ωαβ.  Lôrém ipsùm dolor sit amet.
+Section Ωαβ.  Lôrém 繁體 ipsùm 简体 dolor こんにちは sit 조선글 amet.
```

During the compilation, I hadn't installed the dependencies, so MikTeX's on-the-fly installation was invoked for the following pakcages:

- xeCJK [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of xeCJK]
- luatexja-fontspec.sty [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of luatexja-fontspec.sty]
- everyhook.sty [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of everyhook.sty]
- svn-prov.sty [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of svn-prov.sty]
- UniJIS2004-UTF32-H [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of UniJIS2004-UTF32-H]
- HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf [image: MikTeX's on-the-fly installation of HaranoAjiMincho-Regular.otf]

I clicked "**Install**" so as to install the missing packages.  The system complained about the missing font "NotoSansCJKSC", which I immediately installed.

```
$ find -path './*article.md' -print0 | \
> while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
> pandoc --pdf-engine=lualatex $file -o ${file%md}pdf
> done
Error producing PDF.
! Package fontspec Error: The font "NotoSansCJKSC" cannot be found.

For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...

l.27   \fi
```

[image: Git Bash error]
[image: MikTeX Console noto]
In my MWE, I'm using `Noto Sans CJK SC` instead of `Noto Sans CJK TC` in an answer for the linked TeX.SE question due to the name of the highlighted LaTeX package in the above screenshot.

After that, I repeated the above command, and the error message was gone.  To produce observable results (to be included in the next section), I used `pdftoppm` (shipped with my MikTeX's installation).

```
$ !find
find -path './*article.md' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do pandoc --
pdf-engine=lualatex $file -o ${file%md}pdf; done
$ find -name '*article.pdf' -exec sh -c \
> 'f="{}"; pdftoppm -png -r 450 "$f" "${f%.*}" 2>/dev/null' \;
$ which pdftoppm
/c/Users/sere/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdftoppm
```

Remarks: thanks to [this helpful one-liner for `{}` placeholder manipulation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/453844/165042) on Unix.SE.  I suppressed the following warning message with `2>/dev/null`.

```
MiKTeX requires Windows 10 (or greater): https://miktex.org/announcement/legacy-windows-deprecation
```

## Results

Here're the output PNG for

- target group (✓ CJK)

  [image: target group output]
- control group (✗ CJK)

  [image: control group output]

To view `pdftoppm -png`'s output in their original dimensions, I suggest clicking on these images to view their in a separate tab.

## Question

How can I get the correct spacing between the greek alphabets (illustrated in the screenshot for the control group's output) with CJK characters (shown in the screenshot for the target group's output)?

[image: desired output]
Remarks: the above screenshot is made with MS Paint.

Comment: I’m not sure, but it seems related to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/675038/how-do-i-use-accented-latin-letters-russian-japanese-in-the-same-document.

Comment: Thank you for your link.  It solves my problem.  I'll make a self-answer to clear this question from the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the adopted answer of [How do I use accented latin letters + russian + japanese in the same document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/675038/126386) (mentioned by @JavierBezos in the comments), I've found the line that resolves this problem.

```tex
\ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2}}
```

pandoc provides the [`header-includes`](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-for-latex) variable in which I can include this line of code.

Regarding the lines

```tex
\usepackage{iftex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX}}
```

I don't include them in that pandoc variable because it's already there in [pandoc's default template](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc-templates/blob/bd5fcc525abf2832e574e28d40ca8e0330802a89/default.latex#L91-L108), which loads the LaTeX package `iftex`.

The configurations for `sansfont` and `monofont` aren't the main focus of this problem.  I've found that these variables are redundant in the following MWE.

```
babel-lang: english
babel-otherlangs: chinese, japanese, korean, greek
```

Including and/or excluding these two lines won't affect the final result.  pandoc's user manual provides more detailed info about the `lang` and `babelfonts` variable.

MWE:

```
---
documentclass: standalone
mainfont: Times New Roman
CJKmainfont: Noto Sans CJK SC
header-includes: |
  \ltjsetparameter{jacharrange={-2}}
---

Section Ωαβ.  Lôrém 繁體 ipsùm 简体 dolor こんにちは sit 조선글 amet.
```

Output:

[image: output figure]